# Session.Log doesn't log message when it executed as First Sequence

Tags: c#, logging, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

When we use session.log in C# custom action which is executed as the First Sequence, it does not log any message.What can we use instead of session.Log to log messages, in first sequence/Immediate type of custom actions.

I got this from Wix help documentation, but doesn't specify about logging:

```
firstSequence
Indicates that the custom action will only run in the first sequence that runs it.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note that custom actions launched by a DoAction ControlEvent can send
>   a message with the Message Method, but cannot send a message with
>   MsiProcessMessage.

Workaround for actions triggered using DoAction would be to use Installer Properties to store custom action logging.

Reference Link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368322%28VS.85%29.aspx